# Flink scala jar doesn't work. "The program caused an error: "

Tags: scala, jar, sbt, apache-flink

Hi i am using `sbt new tillrohrmann/flink-project.g8` to create a default project then i just copy paste my code and update build.sbt as `assembly / mainClass := Some("artidokuz.FlinkCsv")`. My package name is `artidokuz`.

If i use Intelij IDEA or `sbt run` my project works but if i use `sbt clean assembly`  and then `sbt run Flink-csv-assembly-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar` (`.jar` generated with assembly). I get an error

```
[error] java.lang.RuntimeException: No main class detected.
[error]         at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:30)
[error] stack trace is suppressed; run last Compile / bgRun for the full output
[error] (Compile / bgRun) No main class detected.
[error] Total time: 0 s, completed Jan 1, 2020, 10:59:04 PM
```

If i try flink UI to push my .jar to server i get.

```
org.apache.flink.client.program.ProgramInvocationException: The program caused an error:
```

Why can't I build my code?

Comment: Please show your sample code. Are you sure that `foo.bar` is the correct FQCN, and not only a package? BTW, `sbt run foo/bar.jar` seems wrong too.

Comment: I was just trying to make it simple to understand let me give more info. My package name is `artidokuz`.
`assembly / mainClass := Some("artidokuz.FlinkCsv")`
`sbt clean assembly`
`sbt run Flink-csv-assembly-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar`

Comment: `sbt run Flink-csv-assembly-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar` is still wrong. This would try to run two tasks: `run` and `Flink-csv-assembly-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar`. You are running that inside the `target` folder? That cannot work. Try `scala Flink-csv-assembly-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar`, but make sure you use the same Scala version as the project.

Comment: I am using the same. I am in the .jar directory. Now i get.
`$ scala Flink-csv-assembly-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar 
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.flink.api.common.typeinfo.TypeInformation
        at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:471)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:588)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
        at artidokuz.FlinkCsv.main(FlinkCsv.scala)... `

Comment: That is expected. Since the flink dependencies are marked as "provided" (those libraries are indeed provided by the flink environment when you run a job), these libraries are not packaged into the jar. But, apparently, your jar had a main-class entry in the manifest and it also found the main class and tried to run it.

Comment: Regarding the `ProgramInvocationException`: have you started the flink cluster already?

Comment: Also, you need to ensure that your cluster uses the same Scala major.minor version as your project. So when you compile with 2.11, your cluster should be the 2.11 variant too. Same goes for 2.12.

Comment: At the time flink wasn't running. Both uses 2.11. When i upload through localhost:8081 UI i get this error.  I only write entry. Do i need to write other parameters? `org.apache.flink.client.program.ProgramInvocationException: The program plan could not be fetched - the program aborted pre-maturely.

System.err: (none)

System.out: (none)`

Comment: I don't know, but that seems to indicate a problem with your code. Maybe the flink server logs can give you a clue...

Comment: Thanks. You can answer the question. What you wrote is enough already.